# When the verb an adverb describes is far away, what should I do?

Tags: grammar

On my another post ([The word "who" is pronounced /hju/, is that some kind of accent?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239532/109190)) I said

> I **carefully** listened to the pronunciation of *who* on Cambridge Dictionary

where I put **carefully** between subject and main verb, which is abnormal and that's what I am worried about.

Usually, [people say "listen carefully"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22listen%20carefully%22)(15 hits on ELL). But for the quoted sentence, that would be

> I listened to the pronunciation of *who* on Cambridge Dictionary **carefully**.

a bit far from "listened", the word **carefully** describes.

What should I do?

similar situation would be

> He answered all the questions proposed by a line of examiners **correctly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Listened **to** the pronunciation..."

Both your examples are correct English (except for missing "to"), and would not be difficult for a native speaker to parse. The adverb can go at the end of the clause or before the verb. Both are correct and normal English.

Placing at the end might give the adverb "end focus" (we tend to remember the last part of a phrase better than the first part) and I think in an imperative sentence I'd prefer "carefully" at the end.  Otherwise it is completely correct to put it in either position.

It is true that with a *very* long separation then the adverb might be better placed close to the verb. The examples you give are not long enough to cause problems